How to make modular architecture in FastAPI?
I have made a modular architecture in FastAPI and getting an error as shown below.
sub_department.py
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from src.db import Base


class SubDepartment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'sub_department'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String, index=True, unique=True)
    department_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('department.id'))
    department = relationship('Department', back_populates='sub_departments')
    consultation_appointment = relationship('ConsultationAppointment', back_populates='sub_department')

department.py
class Department(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'department'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String, index=True, unique=True)
    sub_department = relationship('SubDepartment', back_populates='department')
    doctor = relationship("Doctor", back_populates='departments')


Error:

if I import all model inmain.py or __init__.py it works but it's unused and i do not think it's the way to fix. how to fix this issue and make sure importing all models in main.py is not best practice.

If module A strongly references module B and vise versa, then you don't have a modular design. Why do you actually have this double references?

thank you KlausD but i need this. i like this pattern to be implemented because it's more cleaner.
As per the documentation, we can use our own name when accessing another instance, such as department.sub_departments, which I need.

Well, if you need it like that, what's your question then?

I have shared you what i have done right? why i am getting above error? how to resolve above error?

I think your error is occurred because you put your tables in separate scripts.
You should create all your tables in an script named models.py. The error said that it can't recognize your Department class and that's because you put it in another script.
you can see an example in below link from fastapi website:
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#create-model-attributescolumns

i have explained the same thing in question right? i want modular pattern for my project and if i import in main.py it works but it's unused in main.py.

do you have model.py script in your root?

If you want to have modular architecture, you should create below scripts in your root:
crud.py- database.py- main.py- models.py- schemas.py-
for more explanation refer to fastapi website.

No i do not have, could you please explain in detail? should i make it? And what should i do inside it?

main.py and init.pyt into root folder is okay but why i need to make other file inside root folder? i have service.py, schemas.py, models.py and routes.py in each module.
let say i have module user, it will have schemas.py, models,py, routes.py and services.py and all these for every module.

You should put all your tables in 'model.py script.  You should put all functions that related to creating, deleting, updating and reading data in 'crud.py script.
You should put the create_engine and sessionmaker and declarative_base in database.py script.
You should put the Pydantic models in schemas.py script.
And finally you should write your APIs in main.py script.

i already have db.py, main.py and all configuration as well. there is only one problem, each module has it's own respective file i.e. models.py, schemas.py, routes.py services.py and i have register all router into main.py. if i just import all models into main.py it wont' have any issue.

How many database and tables do you have?

i have one database and 15 to 20 tables. but that won't affect.

ok, you can create all tables in model.py and import it in main.py.finally you must import all these four scripts in main.py.

I have used alembic and imported all models in env.py(alembic) file which is suggested by it's documentation. so, we do not need to import all models in main.py. but still facing same issue.
